# How to align sub menu to the right

Tags: html, css

I have found a menu I would like to use on my website.

Only issue is that I have some sub menus that you can not see on screen.
So I want to get the sub menu to go to left instead of to the right which it does now.

I have tried various things with margin and right:0; but can not find the right solution. Can someone please help ?

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700);
#cssmenu {
  background: #4cb6ea;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul:after,
#cssmenu:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: auto;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li {
  max-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #000000;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 13px;
  right: 15px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li.has-sub:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 15px;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 15px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  padding: 11px 10px 11px 20px;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul li ul li.active > a {
  color: #4cb6ea;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover:after,
#cssmenu ul li ul li.active:after {
  background: #4cb6ea;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul > li {
  max-height: 72px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
  right: 100%;
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: height .2s;
  -moz-transition: height .2s;
  -ms-transition: height .2s;
  -o-transition: height .2s;
  transition: height .2s;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 40px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  top: 16px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #4cb6ea;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 21px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active:after {
  height: 100%;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:after {
  background: #000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:before,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:before {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul > li {
  max-height: 72px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
  width: 170px;
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li {
  width: 170px;
  display: block;
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu > ul {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
    transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-right ul li a {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul.open {
    max-height: 1000px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.25);
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul > li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul > li:after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:before,
  #cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:after,
  #cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul,
  #cssmenu ul li ul li ul,
  #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul li ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    right: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul li,
  #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
    max-height: 999px;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul li a {
    padding: 8px 20px 8px 35px;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul ul li a {
    padding: 8px 20px 8px 50px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > a {
    color: #000000;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    right: 20px;
    top: 16px;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    right: 20px;
    top: 26px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   

    <script type="text/javascript">
   ( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#cssmenu').prepend('<div id="menu-button">Menu</div>');
   $('#cssmenu #menu-button').on('click', function(){
      var menu = $(this).next('ul');
      if (menu.hasClass('open')) {
         menu.removeClass('open');
      }
      else {
         menu.addClass('open');
      }
   });
});
} )( jQuery );

</script>
   <title>CSS Menu</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 4</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 5</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 6</span></a></li>

      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
<html>
```

I want sub menu to go to the left instead of to the right

Comment: Code snippet dosent seem to run, could you fix?

Comment: In order for your items to go left instead of right, you need to change your 
`#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul` from left 100% to right 100% and left auto, however, it causes your items to go off the screen as your second nav item is larger than your home link and you set the sub nav items to be 100% width: https://jsfiddle.net/w7s9o34k/.  I would say too that it's probably bad ux too as nearly all submenus open out to the right

Comment: But in this case when you put mouse over product. The menu that opens, still open to the right. How can I change so it opens to the left ?

Comment: and snippet should run now @Dementic

Answer (score 0):

Your sub menu a tags have 50px of padding pushing them to the right

```
#cssmenu ul li ul ul li a {

    padding: 8px 0px 8px 50px;

}
```

If you want them on the left just reduce that right padding

Comment: That dosnt changed anything :/

Comment: It only moves that text in the box, but it does not moved the dropdown box itself. I want the white box that comes down to go to the left instead og right

Comment: did you reduce the padding? In code i pasted the padding is 50px for the right hand side. You need to reduce that. Try changing it to 10px

Comment: I think I found the right spot:

#cssmenu ul li ul li {
  max-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  background: #ffffff;
  left: -30px;
}

when I add left -30px here it moves like I wanted :)